# PostGis, export Svg in pixels

Tags: postgis-2.0, svg

I'm new to GIS. It is very intersting.

I have installed Postgis, insert shapefile, get data in SVG without problem (ST_AsSVG).

Now, I'd like to export the same svg but in pixel to add it on top of an image. Is it possible directly in the SQL query?

(I can parse the SVG in JS or PHP and convert every point...)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you mean you want to convert it to a raster? Most graphics software can handle that.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I needed svg to manage interaction in javascript.

Comment: Did you consider using the viewBox attribute ?
http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/1.2T-old/publish/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally manage to do that with st_scale and st_translate.

Comment: Can you say us how did you do that please ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but if you connect to your database with Qgis, then you'll be able to export it in SVG.

Comment: I finally manage to do that with st_scale and st_translate. Thanks for your help.